# I don't want the scrollbars when creating a canvas of full width and height

Tags: p5.js

When I create a canvas of windowWidth and windowHeight, then it makes the scrollbars on the editor. How do I make the scrollbars hidden and the canvas size should be fit to the screen in JavaScript or CSS?
I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: This has less to do with the canvas size and more with how `windowWidth` and `windowHeight` don't exclude the toolbars of your browser (including the navigation bar). It's a common HTML/CSS problem, so you may want to find out how you can get the width or height of your actual 'viewable' window using JS